# Pros/Cons of using the same column as the foreign key of two different tables?

Tags: database

Imagine you have a platform, where users can write articles. Those articles are divided into two different tables depending on their type: you have type1 and type2 articles. You need different columns for each type of article and you need to handle them slightly different, hence why you split them up into two tables.

Despite those two types of articles being saved on two separate tables, you want to use their primary keys as foreign keys on the same column in tables, where the type of the articles doesn't matter, for example to keep track of their views, favourites, likes/dislikes, flags, whatever you have. It could look like this:

```
id | type | articleId | whatever
===+======+===========+=========
1  | 1    | 1         | ...     
---+------+-----------+---------
2  | 2    | 1         | ...     
---+------+-----------+---------
3  | 1    | 2         | ...     
---+------+-----------+---------
```

"type" basically defines with which table you should join "articleId" to, meaning that type and articleId combined are always unique.

What are the pros and cons to this? This kind of table will grow very quickly over time and I fear this could slow down queries a lot if you have to join tables based on another column. Should I keep separate tables for each articletype for favourites, views, etc?

Comment: Pros and Cons are qualificators for compare two different methods but you pointed out only one. I think you have no clue about a second method. Am I right?

Comment: @PeterRader Ha! I see what you did there. But no. I mean, my last sentence is kinda a second method, isn't it? And you don't need two methods to have pros and cons anyway. You have one method. This method has good qualities and bad qualities, independant of other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional join targets certainly don't sound ideal to me.  I'm not sure the RDBMS could even maintain the integrity in that case.  Instead, consider an approach where you centralize the identifiers in a kind of super-table and then have all of your other tables reference that.

For example, consider a table of articles:

```
Articles
--------
ID (PK, IDENTITY)
(any other info common to all articles)
```

Then your different "types" have FKs to that:

```
Type1Articles
--------
ID (PK, FK to Articles)
(info about type 1 articles)

Type2Articles
--------
ID (PK, FK to Articles)
(info about type 2 articles)
```

The other tables which extend article info can reference the same super-table.  For example, if you have a many-to-many table linking articles of any type to, let's say, tags:

```
ArticleTags
--------
ArticleID (PK, FK to Articles)
TagID (PK, FK to Tags)
```

Or perhaps you have a table which has a many-to-many which applies *only* to articles of a given type.  You can still reference that table and the constraints would apply across the board:

```
Type1ArticleWidgets
--------
ArticleID (PK, FK to Type1Articles)
WidgetID (PK, FK to Widgets)
```

Basically, start with the information that universally describes an `Article` (even if the only universally common information is just the key identifier), then hang other sub-tables off of that table.